# Mapping not found for field "image" vichupolader symfony2

Tags: php, image, symfony, orm, vichuploaderbundle

I'm trying to make a OneToOne relation between an Image entity and a user Entity Like that :

Image :

```
    /**
 * Image
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="image")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="SocialNetworkBundle\Repository\ImageRepository")
 * @Vich\Uploadable 
 */
class Image {

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * NOTE: This is not a mapped field of entity metadata, just a simple property.
     * 
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="user_image", fileNameProperty="imageName")
     * @Assert\File(
     *     maxSize = "1024k",
     *     mimeTypes = {"image/png", "image/jpeg", "image/jpg"},
     *     mimeTypesMessage = "Please upload a valid PDF or valid IMAGE"
     * )
     * 
     * @var File
     */
    private $imageFile;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $imageName;

    /**
     * Set imageName
     *
     * @param string $imageName
     *
     * @return Image
     */
    public function setImageName($imageName) {
        $this->imageName = $imageName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get imageName
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getImageName() {
        return $this->imageName;
    }

}
```

User :

```
    /**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="UserBundle\Repository\UserRepository") 
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 */
class User extends BaseUser {

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, unique=false)
     * @Assert\Length(min=2, max=100)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="SocialNetworkBundle\Entity\Image", cascade={"persist", "merge", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="image_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * @Assert\Valid()
     */
    private $image;

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setName($name) {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set image
     *
     * @param \SocialNetworkBundle\Entity\Image $image
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setImage(\SocialNetworkBundle\Entity\Image $image = null) {
        $this->image = $image;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get image
     *
     * @return \SocialNetworkBundle\Entity\Image
     */
    public function getImage() {
        return $this->image;
    }

}
```

and Form builder of the user :

```
    class RegistrationFormType extends BaseType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
        // add your custom field
        $builder->add('name')
             ->add('roles', 'collection', array(
               'type' => 'choice',
               'options' => array(
               'choices' => array(
                   'ROLE_ADMIN' => 'Admin'))))

                ->add('image', VichFileType::class, array(
                    'required' => false,
                    'allow_delete' => true, // not mandatory, default is true
                    'download_link' => true, // not mandatory, default is true
                    ))

                ;

    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'user_registration';
    }
}
```

this error appears to me :

> Mapping not found for field "image"

how can i resolve that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. There is no Need to add `@Vich\Uploadable` for the `User` class, you can remove that annotation.
2. In the form Type `RegistrationFormType` Image is not of Type `Vich\Uploadable` , you should create a form type for `Image` class let's cll it `ImageType` for example and add this to it :

   ```
     $builder->add('name')
         ->add('image', VichFileType::class, array(
               'required' => false,
               'allow_delete' => true, // not mandatory, default is true
               'download_link' => true, // not mandatory, default is true
               ))

           ;
   ```
3. In `RegistrationFormType` reference your image type :

   ```
    ->add('image', new ImageType(),array(...))
   ```